# Symfony2 - Array of data

Tags: symfony

This is the last problem I am facing with Symfony2.  So, I am using a normal form, not the form builder.

I have one table called alert which has the standard fields.  I have a second table called booking_class which has an alert key in it which is linked to the alert table.  Its a one to many relationship.  In my form, I have something like

```
<input type="text" name="na_booking_class[]">
<input type="text" name="na_booking_class[]">
```

So this input is placed into an array.  Now in my controller, I presume that this will give me my array of data

```
$alert->setBookingClass($request->get('na_booking_class'));
```

However, setBookingClass only accepts a String.  So I need to somehow loop this array and pass the String values to setBookingClass.

How would this be achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get an array from this `$request->get('na_booking_class');` then you can use:

```
 $arrBooking = $request->get('na_booking_class');
    foreach($arrBooking as $booking) {
       $alert->setBookingClass($booking);
     }
```

Try with this.